# whats the maximum values accepted by redis' LPUSH list operation?

Tags: redis

Redis offers the [LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) operation.

```
LPUSH key value [value ...]
```

What is the maximum number of values supported by a single operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding to this: http://redis.io/topics/data-types

> The max length of a list is 2^32 - 1 elements (4294967295, more than 4 billion of elements per list).

I bet you can use this number of arguments at once too, but maybe you'll run into a timeout with your client.

When your question is about performance, I guess this is nice to read/know.

- http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert
- http://redis.io/topics/pipelining
- http://redis.io/topics/latency

## update

### tias - bash plaintext parser

```
22:15 $ echo lpush works {1..1038} | redis-cli 
(integer) 1038
✔ ~ 
22:15 $ echo lpush worksnot {1..1039} | redis-cli 
(integer) 1038
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
(error) ERR unknown command '1039'
✔ ~ 
22:15 $ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> llen works
(integer) 1038
127.0.0.1:6379> llen worksnot
(integer) 1038
127.0.0.1:6379> llen worksnot
```

So it looks like the limit is 1038.

### lua resp

```
> args = {'lpush', 'mylist'}
> for n = 1,100000 do
>> table.insert(args, tostring(n))
>> end
> 
> resp = require("resp")
> client = resp.new("127.0.0.1", 6379)
> client:call(unpack(args))
100000
> client:call('llen', 'mylist')
100000
```

100k is fine with lua. 1m is too much. lua (not redis!) runs into `stdin:1: too many results to unpack` because of the max stack size (*guessing*).

I still bet that you can push the max length of a list at once ... in case your environment (programming language, physical memory size, ...) can handle it.

Comment: thanks @Markus, "I bet you can" is not the imperative answer I was looking for. The perf data is interesting though.

Comment: great expansion on the error. I'll have to try with my own client to be sure. Are you familiar with the redis source to see if the incoming message has a limitation on the buffer?